# Round integer to nearest thousand

Tags: flutter, dart, rounding

Is there a way to round int number

73400 -> 73000

and

73500 -> 74000

Comment: is there any condition that the number is a 5 digit number?

Comment: Divide by 1000. Round. Multiply by 1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int number = 73400
return round(number/1000.0)*1000
```

Comment: where did you define round()??

Comment: @Brendan round() the exact definition of the rounding operator depends on your application. Here, rounding to the [nearest integer with a round half up tie breaking rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding) probably makes most sense. E.g. round(73.4)=73, round(73.5)=round(73.6)=74. This operator is present in Excel and most programming/scripting languages. Alternatively, you could consider a [ceil() or a floor()](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) operator instead.